# Remove all references to Parallels 7 Windows 7 VM programs

Tags: spotlight, parallels-desktop

My system has been polluted with references to programs residing in a Windows 7 VM in Parallels 7.

For example, Windows programs show up in Spotlight, and in Safari settings under **General->Default browser** I get an annoyingly long list of irrelevant Windows programs.

I've tried to disable "Share Windows applications with Mac" in Parallels settings, to no avail.

[This blog post](http://gregsumner.blogspot.se/2012/07/how-to-prevent-windows-applications.html) suggests to add the **Applications (Parallels)** folder to the Spotlight privacy list, but I can't do that because I don't have that folder. I deleted it some months ago in an unsuccessful attempt to remove the same references as now.

The VM is on a USB disk that's usually not connected so these references must be stored in OS X somewhere. How and where are this links stored and how can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that may be specific to my setup, buy may be useful to others too.

- I had moved the folder with the Windows applications shortcuts
  elsewhere and had forgotten about it. I deleted this folder.
- I deleted duplicates from Finder's 'Open With' menu using `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user` followed by `sudo killall Finder`. You may read more about it [here](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2013/02/getting-rid-of-open-with-duplicates/).